# android listview parsing in asynctask and passing the response

Tags: android

I have asynctask class in which i am performing consuming the webservice and parsing the response.  After parsing i am obtaining list<>. how can i pass to my other class?.

here is my asynctask class

```
String response;
    List<Item> lstresponse_locations = null;
//  CustomAdapter CustAdapter;
//  List<Item> lstresult = new ArrayList<Item>();
//  ListView lstcities;



//  String params;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\

        SendRequesttoServer(params);
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

// getting response from webservice

    public void SendRequesttoServer(String[] params) {

        try {

        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        request.addProperty("CityName", params[0]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope res = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        res.dotNet = true;
        res.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE call = new HttpTransportSE(url);

        SoapPrimitive result;
        call.call(SOAP_ACTION, res);
        result = (SoapPrimitive) res.getResponse();
        ParseLocations Objparselocations = new ParseLocations(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(result.toString()
                            .getBytes("UTF-8")));
        lstresponse_locations = Objparselocations.parse();

        response = lstresponse_locations.toString();
            // lstCities.toArray();

        System.out.println(lstresponse);
    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

how can i pass the response?. 
Thanks ramu

Comment: your question is pretty vague. Care to explain a bit more?

Comment: simply you can use pojo classes right?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is performed on the main UI thread. There, you will handle the result.

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, the result returned from doInBackground method is available in onPostExecute as a param. Just do what you want with result in onPostExecute. See javadoc for AsyncTask for details and examples

Comment: @R.J: i want to use the list returned from my asynctask class to the customadapter.. this is wat i wanted to do Customadapter adapter = new  Customadapter(Citieslocation.this, list_frm_asynctask);                 lstcity.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

String Return by doInBackground to post execute so result in postExceute is your response

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
Log.d("Response: ",result);

}
```

Comment: i need to use the list returned from asynctask class to the customaddapter.. how can i do that??.. please guide me on it.

Comment: initialise the list inside ascntask

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the onPostExecute in you activity itself and create a adapter object inside of the onPostExecute and set the adapter to your listview like

```
Class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle args) {
     ......
     ......
     new MyAsyncTask() {

       public void onPostExecute(List<Object> list) {
          listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(list));
       }

     }.execute(params);
     .......
     ........
   }
}
```

**Edit** :
In your AsyncTask class make the third parameter as List like

```
class MyAsync extends AsycnTask<String, Integer, List<Object>>
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass your `ListView` and its `Adapter` to the `AsyncTask` in the constructor, set the `Adapter` in the `onPostExecute()` method. Worked fine for me